# PowerShell error uploading blob text to Azure: UploadText(string)

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a powershell module which attempts to upload a blob to azure storage.  Everything checks out until the last line which actually uploads the blob.

I receive the following error:

```
Exception calling "UploadText" with "1" argument(s): 
"The specified resource does not exist."
At line:1 char:1
    + $blob.UploadText("asdasdfsdf")
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageClientException
```

I have also tried using the overload with 3 args, but the same issue exists there as well.

Here is the module:

```
Function Add-BlobText
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position = 0)]
      [string]
      $StorageAccount,

      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position = 1)]
      [string]
      $Container,

      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position = 2)]
      [string]
      $BlobName,

      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
      [string]
      $BlobText
) #end param

Add-Type -Path "C:\Assemblies\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll"

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "MySubName"

$secondaryKey = (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $storageAccount).Secondary

$creds = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey($StorageAccount,$secondaryKey)

$cloudStorageAccount = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount($creds, $true)

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient]$cloudBlobClient = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient($cloudStorageAccount.BlobEndpoint)

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer]$blobContainer = $cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference($Container)

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob]$blob = $blobContainer.GetBlobReference($BlobName)

$blob.UploadText($BlobText)     

} #end Function Add-BlobText
```

### ***Update:***

I have been able to get this working as a binary module (below).  If anyone can figure out why `UploadText()` works within a binary module but throws an exception in a script module, please let me know.

```cs
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "BlobText")]
public class AddBlobText : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 0)]
    public string StorageAccount { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1)]
    public string Container { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 2)]
    public string BlobName { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public string BlobText { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddScript("Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'MySubName'");
        string keyScript = "( Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName " + StorageAccount + " ).Secondary";
        ps.AddScript(keyScript);
        Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
        string secondaryKey = result[0].ToString();
        StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(StorageAccount, secondaryKey);
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);
        var blob = container.GetBlobReference(BlobName);
        blob.UploadText(BlobText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your container does not exist. You should call `CreateIfNotExist` after initializing the container to make sure it exists:

```
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer]$blobContainer = $cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference($Container)
$blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist() <-- Here
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob]$blob = $blobContainer.GetBlobReference($BlobName)
$blob.UploadText($BlobText)
```

Comment: It definitely exists. I have also succeeded in getting the exact same code (converted) to work as a binary module vs. a script module

Answer (score 2):

This error is very ambiguous and misleading but there are instances' where Azure Storage can get "confused". Looking at Sandrino's example and specifically this line,

```
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob]$blob = $blobContainer.GetBlobReference($BlobName)
```

Not that Sandrino's answer is your issue but the exception you encountered will happen when passing a Url or possibly other confusing key strings to Azure Storage Containers.

Unfortunately I am not a Powershell guy but here is a reproducing example then fix in C#.

```
    public void Save(string objId, T obj)
    {
        CloudBlob blob = this.container.GetBlobReference(objId); // Problematic if a URL
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/json";

        var serialized = string.Empty;
        serialized = serializer.Serialize(obj);

        if (this.jsonpSupport)
        {
            serialized = this.container.Name + "Callback(" + serialized + ")";
        }
        blob.UploadText(serialized);
    }
```

Assume that **this.container** is a valid blob storage instance pointing to *http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/sggames* or whatever you have for a valid container.

And **objId** is a key that contains a Url like *https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawk4Dw9sLxSc-zmdWQHdZNcyzkTcvKUkhiE* ...and yes this can happen, in my case this is an actual identity claim from Google using Azure ACS.

After the *GetBlobReference* call the blob instance has become corrupt which now looks at a messed up Uri -> *https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawk4Dw9sLxSc-zmdWQHdZNcyzkTcvKUkhiE*

Unfortunately the solution to simply call **$blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist()** is not a solution and wouldn't work. Key's that contain a Uri structure will simply be used to re-interpret the blob storage location.

The work around (other than daredev's Update) would be something like this:

```
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(claim, UriKind.Absolute) && HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(claim).Count > 0)
{
    claim = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(claim)[0];
}
```

Add this code within my method above to clean up any Uri's, but you could use any appropriate method like Base64 encoding URLs if you need to maintain the full key.

Here are the before and after images showing the results as I described.

**The bad:**

[image: notice the bad URI]
notice the bad URI

[image: this bad URI munged up the actual storage blob location]
this bad URI munged up the actual storage blob location

[image: here is the same exception dardev had]
here is the same exception daredev had

**The good:**

[image: the new scrubbed key, notice it's just the value on the URL's query string]
the new scrubbed key, notice it's just the value on the URL's query string

[image: Azure Storage URI looks good now]
Azure Storage URI looks good now

[image: Eureka!]
Eureka!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the PowerShell script I use to upload a file to Azure Blob: [Uploading to Azure Storage](http://thecodegarden.net/uploading-to-azure-storage/)

```
$SubscriptionName = ""
$SubscriptionId = ""
$DestContainer = ""
$StorageAccountName = ""
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile "<Location of the publishsettings-file>"
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -CurrentStorageAccountName $StorageAccountName
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "<File you want to upload>" -Container $DestContainer
```

Comment: what if you want to upload texts, not a file